# Is there a finite amount of mass in the universe?

Tags: energy, mass, universe

So, I'm not too physics savvy but I am curious to ask. Is there a finite amount of mass in the universe? or is there more and more being created from somewhere or something? If the universe is infinite, and there's a finite amount of mass, that just seems kinda weird I guess.

Hopefully this isn't too dumb a question...

Comment: This question is a duplicate of the one linked to by Qmechanic, and none of the answers given here are correct.

Comment: GI don't know why so many people think that the universe is "infinite". It depends on what sense you talking in. There are currently two possible endings of the universe. A big crunch or an ever expanding universe (this one has two sub possibilities). If you say that the universe will expand infinitely, then the universe _can_ be infinite, but it will take an infinite time. But surely the matter in it will never be infinite. Not only will it take infinite energy, if it was infinite, the universe will have infinite curvature, and thus 0 size.