# Finite amount of matter and space

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, multiverse

(Please bear with me.)
If the universe included multi-universes, and black holes transferred matter between them, AND yet there was a large, but FINITE amount of matter and space, How would that max-limit change our understanding/perception or theories of the universe? Would it make any difference or change current concepts?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37729/2451 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/24017/2451

Comment: The understanding is that there is a limit to the amount of matter in the universe. While space is infinite, matter is not. If matter was infinite, gravity would be infinite. That said, if space was finite, I'm not sure how it would change physics

Comment: To me the question makes no sense. Black holes contain matter and do not spew out matter, thus we cannot know of other universes in the way you set up the question: no white holes have been observed. So there would be no difference to the universe we are in now.

Answer (score 1):

You should do some research regarding early models of our universe as expanding, contracting, or static. A static universe has implications for the energy use in the universe.

Regardless most of the physics would be identical, only perhaps Relativity would be any different, as it is the only area of physics which deals with such large distances.